# Not able to control Power Options settings in XFCE4 with Kali Linux?

Tags: xfce, xfce4-terminal

I'm using Kali Linux for my pentest environment. To my needs, I found that XFCE is a better alternative as an interface for the distro & I particularly like it as it is.

However, lately I noticed .. I'm not able to tune the settings for the lockscreen which presently *turns on* after 2 minutes of *idle time*. I wanted to change this into *turn off*.

I did my research:

1. There is no way my system settings show me an option to tune this.
2. I used the CLI for xscreensaver-demo as posted in XFCE forum to no avail.

Here's my `lock` application:

`root@foxtrot:~# ps -ef | grep lock
root        27     2  0 qun14 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root       705     1  0 qun14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vmware-vmblock-fuse -o subtype=vmware-vmblock,default_permissions,allow_other /var/run/vmblock-fuse
root       855   839  0 03:13 pts/7    00:00:00 grep lock
root      1210  1178  0 qun14 ?        00:00:01 light-locker
root      1316  1202  0 qun14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/wrapper-1.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libactions.so 16 10485791 actions Action Buttons Log out, lock or other system actions`

I need to know how do I find the `power manager` options in order to get this disabled?

Comment: remove xscreensaver completely.

Comment: The `xscreensaver` application never existed. It gives me `command not found`. It never shipped with this version.

Comment: then remove the package which brings you that lockscreen.

Comment: my `ps -ef` shows the several ones which I have had mentioned at OP. Not sure, which ones to have uninstalled. Also, wouldn't it have aftereffects? Additionally, can you let me know what command do I issue to bring up the `power options` utility or atleast find which `power manager` does XFCE4 use?